# Is there away setting UI Graphic Context drawing attribute once, instead of on draw everytime?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigraphicscontext

I have a Canvas UIView as below. (Following https://youtu.be/E2NTCmEsdSE)

```
class Canvas: UIView {
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect){
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        // Other codes
        
        context.setLineWidth(10)
        context.setLineCap(.round)
        context.strokePath()
    }
    
    // Other codes
}
```

Looks like I can only `setLineWidth` and `setLineCap` inside the `draw` function. That means whenever a draw happens, they will get set again and again.

I wonder, is there a way for me to set the drawing attribute once per launch and not to set over and over again?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK UIKit uses contexts to draw almost everything, changing attributes globally would have a huge impact.

What you could do is to extend `CGContext` to either set the attributes you want or perform the stroke with the attributes you want.

```
extension CGContext {
  func applyAppStyle() {
    context.setLineWidth(10)
    context.setLineCap(.round)
  }

  func strokeWithAppStyle() {
    context.setLineWidth(10)
    context.setLineCap(.round)
    context.strokePath()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @EmilioPelaez. Moving to another function is fine. But the fact is it is still called within `draw`, hence get triggered over and over away. I'm thinking not to set it over and over again. Not sure if this is possible, or context attribute just need to set all the time?

Answer (score 0):

As you've been told, you can certainly move the multiple lines of code off to a utility function if you don't like having them march down the page inside the `draw` method.

Another possibility is to construct, in advance, in code, a UIImage (by drawing into *its* context), and then just draw *that* into the view context in the `draw` method. Surprisingly, though, that is *less* efficient than what you are doing, because it means storing all the pixels and then copying them all into the context at draw time.

The important thing to understand is that your code is correct, as it stands. What you are doing is what you do. Your code is not inefficient or slow; it may seem *verbose*, but that's just the way things are. Drawing commands are highly optimized; drawing is, after all, the very essence of app display.

Keep in mind that the context does not necessarily persist, and that calls to `draw` are not particularly frequent (indeed, it is not uncommon for a view to be told to draw just once in the lifetime of the app).

So just obey the rules: when you are told to draw, do the complete drawing.

Comment: Thanks, @Matt. I'm just curious as in Android, we can set the `Paint()` value to set line width etc is done outside the `onDraw` function, and hence it only set once regardless of how many times the `onDraw` is called. But in iOS, looks like we need to set the `context.setLineWidth(10)` during `draw`, which seems to be doing the same thing over and over...  so I'm confuse in that regard.

Comment: I stand by my answer.